# Please change the association of my chatroom from TeX to Travel SE

Tags: support, chat, stackexchange

I created a chat room to promote the [Korean Language Proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/74083/korean-language?referrer=_bGLWL4a0nyN5qIsOP5VxA2) at Area51 here:

http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30769/korean-language-discussion-room-commit-stage

However during creation it got associated to TeX.SE by mistake. It turns out that I can [neither change this nor delete the chatroom to start over](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268517/how-can-i-change-the-related-site-for-a-chatroom-after-the-room-is-created) and [I was told that a moderator at TeX.SE should be able to do it for me](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/268517/how-can-i-change-the-related-site-for-a-chatroom-after-the-room-is-created#comment870466_268517).

So I request the powers that be at TeX.SE to change the association of this chat room to something else (preferably travel.SE, or if that is not possible for some reason, then to Area51 itself)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should now be done: I hope this shows up for you.

Comment: Thank you, it's associated with Area51 now